# How to hide certain sections using gatsby-theme-i18n-react-i18next?

Tags: localization, gatsby, react-i18next

I have a project that uses Gatsby and for localization, I have used [gatsby-plugin-react-i18next](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/) plugin. I have to hide few sections in the menu for some languages. How to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a conditional rendering.

```
const YourComponent = (props) => {
  const { language } = useI18next();

  return (
    <div>
    {language === 'en' ? <OneComponent /> : <OhterComponent />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can extend the condition to a function that returns a component:

```
const YourComponent = (props) => {
  const { language } = useI18next();

  const handleComponent = () =>{
    if(language === 'en') return <OneComponent />
    else(language === 'es') return <OhterComponent />
  }  
 
  return (
    <div>
    {handleComponent()}
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can see in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/#plugin-api), the exposed `language` variable holds the current language.